# What the hint to find the probability if given mean and variance?

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

The amount of time needed for a printer to print a file is a random variable with mean $E(X_i)=20$ minutes and variance $var(X_i)=4$ minutes$^2$. The times needed for difference file are independent from each other. Find the probability that the printer prints less than 15 files in 5 hours.

I have thought for a hour to answer this question. I'm not have an idea to do it.
I cannot find the probability if given mean and variance. What the hint to answer this question?

Comment: Is there no other information given, such as the type of distribution (normal, etc.)? If not, I think all you can calculate with this information is a bound.

Comment: Unfortunately, no information for type of distribution in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that fewer than $\ 15\ $ files are printed in $\ 5\ $ hours is
$$
P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{15}X_i>5\times60\Big)\ .
$$
You're probably expected to appeal to the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Convergence_to_the_limit) to deduce that $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^{15}X_i\ $ is approximately [normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean $\ 15\times20\ $ minutes and variance $\ 15\times4\ $ minutes${}^2$. However, since $\ 15\times20=$$
 5\times 60=$$\,300\ $, you only really need for $\ X_i\ $ to be symmetrically distributed about its mean to deduce that
$$
P\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{15}X_i>5\times60\Big)=\frac{1}{2}\ .
$$